# How to delay multiple thread groups in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am executing the test plan in which I have created **5 Thread Groups** for execution. **I want to execute these thread groups parallelly but want to add some delay time in each thread group suppose 10 seconds of delay I want.**

- The **first** thread group will be executed and after 10 seconds
- The **second** Thread group will be executed parallelly and after again 10 seconds
- And the **third** thread group will be executed parallelly till to reach the last one like this.

Below is the Image for more information that how I have created my test plan. Please refer to the same. (*Currently, I have used only 2 thread groups to meet the expected outcomes*)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered another Thread Group implementation, for example [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) where you can specify `Initial Delay`:

[image]

Ultimate Thread Group can be installed as a part of the [Custom Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Thread-Groups) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/):

[image]

---

You can achieve the same using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler, just add it as the first Sampler to your Thread Group and specify 10 minutes (or whatever) delay there

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely use the ultimate thread group as well. But for now I have used the Multiple Thread Groups and in second thread group I have used the `Flow Control Action` and used `Synchronising timer` as a child of the `Flow Control Action`. **Is It significant to use the synchronising timer with Flow Control Action ??**

Comment: If you just put the Flow Control Action - it will delay each thread (virtual user) separately. Introducing the Synchronizing Timer will act as a ["rendezvous" point](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/08/31/creating-rendezvous-points-in-lr-sap-loadrunner-by-hpe/) so JMeter will wait until all the threads are available and then all of them will start "waiting" for 10 minutes at the same time. See [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/) for more information.

Comment: Okay Now I got It . Thanks a lot !! One Last question can you please tell me how I can read CSV data and place it in Number Of Threads (Users) in particular thread group ? Suppose I have set first Thread Group  as threads count to 2 so I have to read 2 from the CSV file. I just don't want to hard code in the Thread Group also for all other thread groups.